# How do I create a "deep" version of this prolog predicate that will affect sublists?

Tags: list, prolog

My current predicate `eo` will remove every other element in a list, starting with the first element.

```
eo([],[]).
eo([_],[]).
eo([_,X|L],[X|R]) :- eo(L,R)].
```

that produces results like

```
?- eo([a,b,c,d,e,f],L).
L = [b,d,f]
```

and

```
?- eo([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],L).
L = [b,d,f]
```

But now, I want to create a "deep" version. This version will also affect sublists. So, the following should hold:

```
?- eo([a,b,c,d,e,[x,y,z],L).
L=[b,d,[y]]
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: What to do with [a,b,c,d,[x,y,z],e] ?

Comment: Essentially, you have to use `is_list(L)` to determine if the item of a list is itself a list, and then call `eo/2` on that item, and then use the result of that to build your result.

Comment: @joel76 that would result in L = b,d,e. In other words, it would remove the sublist entirely as the sublist itself is an odd indexed element in the original list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, taking what you have now, this is basically the change you have to make:

```
eo([],[]).
eo([_],[]).
eo([_,X|L],[X2|R]) :- 
    (is_list(X) ->   %% is X a list?
         eo(X, X2)   %%  - yes, so recur on it
    ;    X2 = X      %%  - no, so just pass it through
    ), 
    eo(L,R).
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not super familar with the arrow operator in prolog. Does it essentially work as an if-else statement?

Comment: @superluigisunshine yes, that is what it does. :)

Comment: `L=[1,2], eo([0,L],[[2]]).` succeeds. Yet, `eo([0,L],[[2]]), L=[1,2].` fails. `is_list/1` is the reason for this problem. You need some instantiation error (or non-termination, if you insist)